# I want to load second view with given frame size

Tags: iphone

[image]

I try to load Second view in MainView with define frame size but don't need to see component of second view. I set size till it weel be appear.

```
-(IBAction)displayNewView:(id)sender {

    [mrView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,150,320,50)];
    [self.view addSubview:mrView]; 
}
```

[image]

i dont want to see second button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Clip Subviews]

Hey, I solved this issue by checking "Clip Subviews".

It will crop rest of the part of view which will not display.

Nice Question with basic issue.

Thanks.

Comment: It's ok mate. Enjoy Coding.:)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Button on Second View. Then It'll display on View when you are loading second view on Main View. Because it's part of Second View.

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: But i dont need to load this so how to i complete this job ,i wont to load second view with define frame size if any component will be present on given frame size then and then only it will appear otherwise i dont need to display,here button already out of frame size till it will be appear.